# how to start a dialog in my c++ share library on mac osx

Tags: c++, macos, dialog

afternoon evrybody.

I write a shared library `test.dylib` for mac osx . now I want to start a dialog to alert user some information in my library. I write an App with `wxWidgets` before ,and I call `system("open /Applications/showUI.app")` to start a seperate app in my library, I don`t like this way however.

I want to alert user with osx system API in cocoa, now how can I?

any ideas ?3Q ...

Comment: You need to use Objective-C++. See [`NSAlert`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSAlert_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

Comment: thanks rightfold.could you give me a detail .do I need write an app with xcode. I just want to popup an information alert in my library.Not start an independent app additionnal.